# Trying to sort props in an object based on values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array(7) [
    { date: 'January', 'Hang with Friends': 100 }, 
    { date: 'February', Chill: 30, Book: 80 }, 
    { date: 'March', Yoga: 40 },
    { date: 'April', Birthday: 200 }, 
    { date: 'May', Gas: 70 }, 
    { date: 'June', Rent: 900, testingsub: 200 }, 
    { date: 'July', 'test sub': 500 },
  ]
```

And I'd like to sort all props in each object if the key isn't date so it ends up like this:

```
Array(7) [
    { date: 'January', 'Hang with Friends': 100 }, 
    { date: 'February', Chill: 30, Book: 80 }, 
    { date: 'March', Yoga: 40 },
    { date: 'April', Birthday: 200 }, 
    { date: 'May', Gas: 70 }, 
    { date: 'June', testingsub: 200, Rent: 900, }, 
    { date: 'July', 'test sub': 500 },
  ]
```

Only one object was changed (index 5), but with a larger dataset I'd like them ordered because I'll be using their values to determine color shade etc.

This is what I tried, but it's not working obviously:

```
  const sortedData = newData.map((item) =>
    Object.entries(item).sort(([key1, value1], [key2, value2]) => {
      if (key1 !== "date" && key2 !== "date") {
        if (value1 > value2) {
          return 1;
        } else if (value2 > value1) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }
    })
  );
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Argument of type '([key1, value1]: [string, number], [key2, value2]: [string, number]) => 0 | 1 | -1 | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: [string, number], b: [string, number]) => number'.
  Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why would you want to sort the keys of an object? Objects are not meant to be ordered (even though their key traversal orders are well-defined and consistent among implementations).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, two things. The error you're getting is not a runtime error, but a type error. So your code probably runs but depending on how strictly you've got your type checking set it, the compiler might refuse to compile.

It tells you exactly what the problem is (although a bit cryptically). The function you pass to `.sort()` must return a `number`, but your function returns `number | undefined`, and that's because there is a missing code path: the `if (key1 !== "date" && key2 !== "date") {` is missing an else condition.

Secondly, you can't sort objects in JavaScript. You can convert an object to an array and sort it like that, which is what you're doing. If you were to convert that array back into an object, your sorting will be lost.

Currently the result of your `sort` is lost for another reason, because you don't assign it anywhere. Now `Array.sort` doesn't return anything, it sorts the array in place. So something like this could work:

```
const sortedData = newData.map((item) => {
    const entries = Object.entries(item);
    entries.sort(...)
    return entries;
}); // note the added `{ .. }` around the map callback function
```

Comment: "*If you were to convert that array back into an object, your sorting will be lost.*": Not really, as long as there are only string keys. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#description), the traversal order are well-defined by modern specs.

Comment: @InSync not quite. I've looked at this in the past. Even if you're using strings, if the string looks like a number, for example `for (let i in { "a": "b", "2": "c" }) console.log(i)`  the order will change. The type of the variable doesn't matter, if it looks like an integer, it will be interpreted as one. I just always use arrays if I'm interested in a specific order, objects can useful for lookups.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I should have made that clearer (all object keys are "string" keys by definition).